# Como evitar a dupla submissão de um formulário ao atualizar a página?

Tags: php

Tenho essa função que é responsável por realizar o registro de um novo usuário no meu formulário, portanto quando eu atualizo ele inseri novamente o ultimo registro, como posso fazer o tratamento para isso não acontecer?

```
   function cadastrarUsuario ($conexao, $titulo){
    //verificando se o formulário foi postado
    if(isset($_POST['frmCadUsuario'])){
        //postou o formulario)
        $usuario = $_POST['txtNomeUsuario'];
        $idade = $_POST['txtIdadeUsuario'];

       if (usuario_cadastrar($conexao, $usuario, $idade));{
            $retornoEsc = "Usuário Cadastrado com Sucesso!";
            $dados = listarDados($conexao);
            require ("view_lista.php");
        }

    }
    else{
        //mostrar o formulário de cadastro
        require ("view_form_cadastro_novo_usuario.php");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nas outras perguntas não consegui obter uma resposta que mostrasse a solução definitiva, tentei alguns exemplos e não obtive êxito.

Comment: A solução que encontrei para o meu problema foi acrescentar antes do '$retornoEsc = "Usuário Cadastrado com Sucesso!";' o seguinte: 'header("location: http://aqui o endereço que deseja retornar");
            exit;'
Nas respostas que obtive nas perguntas duplicadas não eram precisas para entender onde devia ser acrescentado o header